# Make PC a slave to the Arduino ADK

Tags: android, arduino

Is there any way to make the PC a USB slave when connecting to the [Arduino ADK](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) which act as the master?

I am aware that both of the USB connections are using master which will make communication hard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use the existing USB interfaces on the PC and Arduino ADK, the PC will be USB host. However, through your coding you can make the PC subservient to the Arduino ADK.